# Plotting gradient descent function in R

Tags: r, plot, gradient-descent

I have implemented a multivariate linear regression in R followed by a batch update gradient descent algorithm. I am now trying to plot the results of this gradient descent.

I have found instructional links on how to create a plot [here](http://www.machinegurning.com/rstats/gradient-descent/) and [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/gradient-descent-in-r/).

The problem with these tutorials is that in both cases, they explicitly define the linear regression equation (also it is not multivariate).

How can I create similar plots to overlay the results of running the `gradDescent` function several times with different learning rates and convergence thresholds in the code listed below:

```
data <- read.csv("Data/Bike-Sharing-Dataset/hour.csv")

# Select the useable features
data1 <- data[, c("season", "mnth", "hr", "holiday", "weekday", "workingday", "weathersit", "temp", "atemp", "hum", "windspeed", "cnt")]

# Set seed
set.seed(100)

# Split the data
trainingObs<-sample(nrow(data1),0.70*nrow(data1),replace=FALSE)

# Create the training dataset
trainingDS<-data1[trainingObs,]

# Create the test dataset
testDS<-data1[-trainingObs,]

# Create the variables
y <- trainingDS$cnt
y_test <- testDS$cnt
X <- as.matrix(trainingDS[-ncol(trainingDS)])
X_test <- as.matrix(testDS[-ncol(testDS)])

int <- rep(1, length(y))

# Add intercept column to X
X <- cbind(int, X)
X_test <- cbind(int, X_test)

# Solve for beta
betas <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y

# Round the beta values
betas <- round(betas, 2)

# Gradient descent 1
gradientDesc <- function(x, y, learn_rate, conv_threshold, max_iter) {
  n <- nrow(x) 
  m <- runif(ncol(x), 0, 1)
  yhat <- x %*% m
  
  cost <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / (2*n)

  converged = F
  iterations = 0
  
  while(converged == F) {
    ## Implement the gradient descent algorithm
    m <- m - learn_rate * ( 1/n * t(x) %*% (yhat - y))
    yhat <- x %*% m
    new_cost <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / (2*n)
    
    if( abs(cost - new_cost) <= conv_threshold) {
      converged = T
    }
    iterations = iterations + 1
    cost <- new_cost
    
    if(iterations >= max_iter) break
  }
  return(list(converged = converged, 
              num_iterations = iterations, 
              cost = cost,
              new_cost = new_cost,
              coefs = m) )
}

out <- gradientDesc(X, y, 0.005, 0.0000001, 200000)
```

**Note**:
The data being used is-

> Bike-Sharing-Dataset
>
> UCI Machine Learning Repository

Answer (score 2):

Because this is the multivariate case, it is difficult to plot `cost` as against parameters. However, it is possible to plot `cost` against number of iterations.

To do that, we need to keep the value of `cost` in every iteration. We can create a `data.frame` in `while` loop and add it to the list to be returned.

```
data <- read.csv("Data/Bike-Sharing-Dataset/hour.csv")

# Select the useable features
data1 <- data[, c("season", "mnth", "hr", "holiday", "weekday", "workingday", "weathersit", "temp", "atemp", "hum", "windspeed", "cnt")]

# Set seed
set.seed(100)

# Split the data
trainingObs<-sample(nrow(data1),0.70*nrow(data1),replace=FALSE)

# Create the training dataset
trainingDS<-data1[trainingObs,]

# Create the test dataset
testDS<-data1[-trainingObs,]

# Create the variables
y <- trainingDS$cnt
y_test <- testDS$cnt
X <- as.matrix(trainingDS[-ncol(trainingDS)])
X_test <- as.matrix(testDS[-ncol(testDS)])

int <- rep(1, length(y))

# Add intercept column to X
X <- cbind(int, X)
X_test <- cbind(int, X_test)

# Solve for beta
betas <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y

# Round the beta values
betas <- round(betas, 2)

# Gradient descent 1
gradientDesc <- function(x, y, learn_rate, conv_threshold, max_iter) {
  n <- nrow(x) 
  m <- runif(ncol(x), 0, 1)
  yhat <- x %*% m

  cost <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / (2*n)

  converged = F
  iterations = 0

  while(converged == F) {
    ## Implement the gradient descent algorithm
    m <- m - learn_rate * ( 1/n * t(x) %*% (yhat - y))
    yhat <- x %*% m
    new_cost <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / (2*n)

    if( abs(cost - new_cost) <= conv_threshold) {
      converged = T
    }

    step <- data.frame(iteration = iterations,
                       cost = cost,
                       new_cost = new_cost)

    if(exists("iters")) {
      iters <- rbind(iters, step)
    } else {
      iters <- step
    }

    iterations = iterations + 1
    cost <- new_cost

    if(iterations >= max_iter) break
  }
  return(list(converged = converged, 
              num_iterations = iterations, 
              cost = cost,
              new_cost = new_cost,
              coefs = m,
              iters = iters))
}
```

Now visualize the `new_cost` for 10000 iteration:

```
out <- gradientDesc(X, y, 0.005, 0.0000001, 10000)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = out$iters, mapping = aes(x = iteration, y = new_cost))+
  geom_line()
```

[image: gradient descent]

Hope it works.